# How to make .jar file read database and serialised .txt file?

Tags: java, sqlite, io, filesystems, executable-jar

I'm trying to make an executable .jar file from a program that uses both an SQLite database and a serialized read/write file system for storage inside the program. We are able to make an executable .jar file, but it doesn't read from any database nor file system that we have written within the program. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does your program already read from a database or from a file?

Comment: @ValerijDobler I've been trying to generate a .jar file from maven, as seen here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html#package_into_jar

Comment: And...? With what result?

Comment: Usually you just have from call in the command line `mvn clean package` from the directory in which the `pom.xml` resides. This will yield in an .jar file inside the target directory.  See [maven lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: @ValerijDobler I was able to get it to read the SQLite database, but I had to restructure the entire architecture of my program, the link I sent in the comment above did not lead anywhere, as when the program tried to find the files/database path which was coded inn, it was unable to find it, I'm suspecting that it has something to do with the .jar file and how that works, I'm unsure though

Comment: You can run a java program through the .class files or combine the .class files together to a jar (it's just a zip actually) and run it instead. Did you added dependencies manually or is everything declared in the pom.xml?

Comment: @ValerijDobler everything is declared in the pom.xml file, it seems to me that the program is unable to find any paths to files after being converted to a .jar

Answer (score 0):

"To make a .jar file read from a database" when you have a Java or Kotlin (or Scala) program which does that you are almost done, you just have to compile it and which provides you a .jar file which does exactly that.

I think your question is what does it take to write a program that does it.
For that you have to think about what your database should be able to handle.

## Read from filesystem

A text file on a disc is very rudimentary but might suffice if the application is just to read/write some persisted state. For that the Java API has all you need, take a look at [Baeldung - read from file via NIO](https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java).

## Read from database

If you need transactions or support for multiple applications working with the persisted storage, a database would be the more sensible thing to use.

Although the Java API again provides you everything you need for that (e.g.[Processing SQL Statements with JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html)) you would need to reinvent the wheel in a sense. The easier thing would be to rely on an [OR-mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) like [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/) or [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/).

For writing enterprise Java software you could overengineer it with [Spring-Boot JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).